# convert this date time string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

is it possible to convert this date time string

```
'20150819130706'
```

to something like this

```
'2015-08-19 13:07:06'
```

Comment: Whence is the source of this poorly-formatted string?  Would it be possible for you to export it another format which is easier for SQL Server to consume?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option:

```
DECLARE @DatetimeString char(14) = '20150819130706'

SELECT  LEFT(@DatetimeString, 4) + '-' + 
        SUBSTRING(@DatetimeString, 5, 2) + '-' + 
        SUBSTRING(@DatetimeString, 7, 2) + ' ' +
        SUBSTRING(@DatetimeString, 9, 2) +':' + 
        SUBSTRING(@DatetimeString, 11, 2) +':' + 
        RIGHT(@DatetimeString, 2)
```

If you want an actual datetime value, you can simply cast the entire thing to datetime:

```
SELECT  CAST(   LEFT(@DatetimeString, 4) + '-' + 
                SUBSTRING(@DatetimeString, 5, 2) + '-' + 
                SUBSTRING(@DatetimeString, 7, 2) + 'T' +
                SUBSTRING(@DatetimeString, 9, 2) +':' + 
                SUBSTRING(@DatetimeString, 11, 2) +':' + 
                RIGHT(@DatetimeString, 2) As datetime)
```

Note: for converting to datetime you need to change the `' '` to `'T'`, see Lad2025's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234838/convert-this-date-time-string/37234917#comment61999124_37234917) to this answer.

Comment: Final result is string.

Comment: @lad2025 I know, that's why I've added the cast at the end.

Comment: Then you could get out-of-range error, because you add `+ ' ' +` instead of `+ 'T' +`. **[demo](http://rextester.com/CQF62757)**

Comment: Of course, but that can be the result of any number or string casted to datetime, since you have no control of the input.

Comment: It clearly looks like `yyyyMMddhhmmss`. The point is that `2015-08-19 13:07:06` is culture depenedent, where `2015-08-19T13:07:06` is not.

Comment: @lad2025: I was under the impression that yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss was independent of everything, including culture. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: For more info search for ISO-8601

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Convert(varchar(19),
cast(Substring('20150819130706', 1,8)
+ ' ' + Substring('20150819130706',9,2)
+ ':' + Substring('20150819130706',11,2) 
+ ':' + Substring('20150819130706',13,2) as datetime),121);
```

Use this query.

Comment: I got an error: "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: Modified my query check please. I missed colons